# Are similar answers bad?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just recently got downvoted twice because I posted an answer that was *similar*, note not the same, as an existing one a couple of minutes beforehand. I also only saw the other answer after I finished writing mine up.

My answer consisted of this regex:

```
@[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z]+@
```

Whereas the other answer consisted of this one:

```
[@][a-z@]+[@]
```

There are 2 main differences between the two:

1. Mine allows for uppercase letters
2. Mine will only accept input in the form of `@word@word@` whereas the other one will accept any number of `@`s in the input and even `@@@`

Also since I posted, and whilst in the grace period, I edited the answer to include an extra, more constrained, solution. Although I am unsure if the downvotes came before or after the edit.

What is the policy on similar answers? Leave them be as is? Suggest an edit to the other one? Comment on the other one? Other?

I know users are free to downvote as they wish but were two downvotes on what was only a similar answer justified?

Comment: The real solution is to clarify the question and avoid guess answers...

Comment: @Tunaki Neither were guess answers and both answered the problem at hand

Comment: Well, should uppercase letters be considered? Should it handle any kind of input? What are all of the possible cases? This would restrict the answers to the relevant problem.

Comment: @Tunaki It wasn't very well described with test cases and all the constraints. But this question was more to ask about similar answers rather than this particular example, that is just what led me to asking this.

Comment: Yes, so the question was unclear (not very well described), and the actual problem is that resulted in any answers being posted at all, instead of asking for clarification. This is the general case.

Comment: Side note - based on answer it is likely question was of insanely low quality with zero research shown... So maybe someone was just friendly to OP and making sure downvoted question does not get blocked from deletion due to more than one answer?

Comment: @Mike I don't really agree... OP here wants some guidance on how similar answers are considered, not why it was downvoted (even if this is what triggered the concern)...

Comment: @Tunaki know you've seen a bazilion questions on Meta, but this seems like a case of "listen to the question, not the impression it gives you"... no? OP wants to know how similar answers are considered.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I am discussing the premise of the question. OP wants to know whether similar answers are bad, and my opinion is that similar answers should not even exist: either the question is clear enough to warrant an answer (or multiple answers using different approaches, but all answering the same question, so they won't be 'similar'), or it isn't and no answers should exist.

Comment: ... that's playing a bit on words, don't you think? similar answers vs multiple approaches is very nearby... but I do agree that in this case, if the question did not specify capitals or not, it may very well be unclear

Comment: @Félix I don't think it is. The answers are labeled as similar here, not because they solve the same task, but because they look the same and solve [slightly different tasks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341502/are-similar-answers-bad#comment432301_341502).

Comment: @Tunaki they solve the same task but one includes more constraints that the other

Comment: see also: [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773)

Comment: @close-voters really? I mean... one of the duplicate target is about *exact* duplicates. Surely you can see the difference between exact duplicate answer and similar answer? The other is about when are downvotes justifiable (which is totally not the emphasis here). The third one *is* about similar answers, but the answer here explains the situation much better. These are poor duplicate targets choices, at best, and poor review/vote decisions, at worse. (I know I may seem in a conflict of interest because I answered here, but you are welcome to tell me how the points in this comment are wrong.)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier your completely missing the point this question only exists because people are too quick to jump on questions that are not clear enough to give a concise answer and lead to a lot of guess answers *(depending on tag popularity)*. What should happen is the question is closed until the OP can add clarity. I'm in complete agreement with Tunaki here.

Comment: @Lankymart My what? ;) Also thanks, but you in turn completely miss the point. I am speaking of this *meta* question, and it's close reasons, not the *main* one. If you read my accepted answer below, I finish by also agreeing with tunaki's point.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I read it afterwards. But you can argue about this meta question as much as you want, the simple point is it wouldn't be needed if people didn't jump on questions before identifying if they are clear and concise enough to answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No**, similar answers are welcome, as different viewpoints on a question help different people understand. We don't all have the same brain.

You should not delete an answer because it is similar. A copy paste answer is not welcome, but a detail can mean everything in a problem. Especially with regexes, actually.

If you feel like commenting, sure, you can do it that way if you feel the other answerer did not think about a specific aspect of the question, however, if you feel like answering (and adding details as to why your answer is different) please do.

---

However, in your case, I'll have to agree with [Tunaki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341502/are-similar-answers-bad/341503?noredirect=1#comment432301_341502) that the question was probably poor, and should not have been answered. If it wasn't clear in the requirements whether OP wanted capital letters to be included or words to be included between `@` characters, it should have been clarified before answering, or not answered at all.

It may very well be that your answer actually answers the question, whereas the other doesn't, or the contrary.

Comment: Agree with this when 'similar' means different viewpoints on the same question, which is indeed something really helpful to have.

Answer (score 13):

There is no "official policy".  Users vote based on whether or not they feel an answer is useful.  If someone feels that your answer isn't useful, as a result of just posting an answer that's no more useful than other existing answers, they're perfectly within their rights to hold and express that viewpoint.  Someone else may feel that your answer adds value not in other answers, and vote accordingly.  At the end of the day the only "official policy" is that the voter should be voting based on whether or not they feel the answer is useful, and the user's reasoning for voting clearly indicates that *they feel* that the answer isn't useful, so they're following the guidelines.

Comment: Why is everyone missing the fact that OP wants guidance on how similar answers are considered?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier You mean the questions they edited in after I posted my answer?  I missed them because I didn't bring my time machine with me today.

Comment: Nope. I'm speaking about "What is the policy on similar answers? Leave them be as is? Suggest an edit to the other one? Comment on the other one? Other?" I mean, what you are saying is helpful, but it specifically focuses on the "why the downvote" aspect, which I don't see as the important part of the question

Answer (score -8):

If your answer in different view point and the way of describing is different that it make a lot of sense. So your answer is always welcome it does not mean that copy above and edit more and post it.

There is some point.

- Editing answer if you agree above and want to add a little bit more.
- If you think to have some miss-understand then just put a comment on it.